# Why won't expandablelistview work with context menus?

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

My app used to use a standard ListView, and registerForContextMenu(getListView()) and everything worked just fine.

I needed to change my app to accommodate nested lists so I replaced the ListView with ExpandableListView.  I changed the Activity to ExpandableListActivity. I also changed my adapter to a tree adapter and implemented a custom view class to populate the list with (based on a FrameLayout view).

Suddenly my context menus stopped working and I can't figure out why.  I can't long click on any of my list items and I'm completely stuck on where to start looking.

Answer (score 0):

Probably another view then your listitems receives the longclick.
I would add OnLongClickListener to all views and create log what listener gets triggered by a longclick.

Otherwise it might help to see something from your code to spot an error.

Comment: It hasn't led to my solution quite yet, but putting in the listener actually made the long click register and the context menu shows up.  I still don't get the selector animation (orange to white fade) and it doesn't respond to D-pad input.

Comment: You could redirect the click to the right view by calling performClick() or performLongClick() on the right view.